# Why use a client side cookie if a PHP session variable persists

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

I'm a bit new to this so here's what I think I know (and I may be wrong).

1. A php session variable can persist long enough for a user to do their thing. If the browser is closed and reopened they have to log back in as the (php) session variable clears on close.
2. The server knows which php session variables belong to which client.
3. Having a client side cookie, which contains the php session ID, is a bit of a vulnerability.

If all this is true, and there's nothing else significant to add to the mix, then why create a client side cookie that could be compromised?

Wouldn't it be better/safer to just use session variables?

Or is php creating a client side cookie automatically which is the vulnerable bit?

Comment: "Having a client side cookie, [snip] is a bit of a vulnerability.". Why?

Comment: Maybe I misread but I was under the impression that cookies could be sniffed, or something, allowing another user to hijack a session? I’m wondering if I can not use client side cookies at all given it’s not an issue to get the user to log back in if they closed the browser?

Comment: If the cookies can be sniffed it means that all traffic can be sniffed (and most likely altered). So cookies or no cookies it doesn't really matter at that point does it.

Comment: Makes sense... so is it the case that when php creates a session there is some sort of automatic client side cookie that links the browser and session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie with session id is neccessary.
It's because, php server really don't know who sent the request.

One of solutions to recognise request owner is a cookie which contanins session id. Only session id. All data assigned to session id is stored on a server, in files or database. Level of security depends on how long your session id is and used entropy.

We can consider some cases when you are exposed for session hijacking.

#### Insufficient Session-ID Length

It can expose your session for bruteforce. We can use some calculations to give it a example. Imagine that you have server which generates session id with 32 bits entropy. Your server can handle 1000 requests per second and you have approximately 1000 authenticated users with valid session id.

Then we can use simple math formula to calculate time in seconds needed to compromise somebody session id.

The formula is taken from [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Insufficient_Session-ID_Length)

After calculations we know that avarage time will be something like **0.6h**

But using key with 128bit entropy (php key has a little more)

That time will be equal to **4.726144e+28h** (**1.6410222e+26 years**)

So it's pretty secure i think.

#### Session side jacking

Imaging that, you have finally implemented sessions with strong entropy. So it can't be guessed using bruteforce. You have also secured with https auth endpoint, so nobody can sniff your password and login. But other parts of your web application dont have https protocol.

Now, if somebody will run your application in public network for example imaginary user Marta, somebody who uses packet sniffing application can easly read Marta's session cookie.

To prevent that situation, you should have secured all parts of your application with https and use valid certificate.

You should also read for [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) security vulnerabilities to make sure that your session is enough secure.

#### Final answer

Yes, session cookie can be enough secure if follows security standards.

Comment: "Using bruteforce you can try to guess the session id and stole someone session." When generating a session id the proper way this is really not relevant.

Comment: A JWT is just as vulnerable to hijacking as a session cookie. The data is stored in a different place (in the JWT instead of the server-side session), but otherwise it's no fundamental difference.

Comment: Of course, using https and sufficient session id length should prevent bruteforce and other popular hijacking methods

Comment: Awesome, thank you! And thanks to everyone who responded

Answer (score 3):

The ID in the client-side cookie tells PHP *which* session is yours.

Answer (score 1):

> The server knows which php session variables belong to which client.

And how does it do that? By storing the session id in a cookie which the client sends back to the server with every request.

> If the browser is closed and reopened they have to log back in as the (php) session variable clears on close.

It's not the PHP session that expires, it's the browser that discards the cookie upon close. The client then has no session id to send to the server anymore. (Unless an explicit expiration time is set on the cookie, in which case the browser will hold on to it.) (And the PHP session *will* eventually expire too, just to be clear.)